# Powershell - Convert DistinguishedName to Name in a Piped Command

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I use this command post in an other of my questions. I'm searching how can I convert the manager field from DistinguishedName to Name (First name, last name)

```
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly  -AccountDisabled:$false | Get-ADUser -Properties Name, manager| select Name, manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it. I'm basically extracting the text in the manager DN from the first instance of "=" to the first instance of ","

```
Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly  -AccountDisabled:$false | Get-ADUser -Properties Name, manager| select Name, @{N='Manager';E={$_.Manager.Substring($_.Manager.IndexOf("=") + 1, $_.Manager.IndexOf(",") - $_.Manager.IndexOf("=") - 1)}}
```

Comment: With the command I posted, the value that return to me is Smith\, John, it's almost the "name" field, I would like to know if it's possible to take the $_manager.substring value and remove the "\" from it ?

Comment: This is getting a bit confusing. If you show me what the full original  text (or example) and what you want to convert it to, I can show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner version of the previous answer.

Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly  -AccountDisabled:$false | Get-ADUser -Properties Name, manager| select Name, @{N='Manager';Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.Manager).name}}